# cookie is not shown in chrome developer tools

Tags: angularjs, cookies, express, google-chrome-devtools

i am using node/express server and angularjs as frontend. server sets the cookie and is shown correctly in the network response. but the cookie is not shown in the resource tab in the chrome developer tools. What are the possible reasons for the same. 
[image: network tab]

[image: request resource]

[image: request resource]

[image: resource tab]

Comment: if the cookie has an expiring time in the past, it would be silently dropped by chrome. It won't appear in the resources tab

Comment: your server sets 3 cookies: admin, remember and sessionID and they all are shown in the resources tab. What cookie do you say is not shown?

Comment: cookie in resource tab in  chrome developer tool is not set. i have added an image

Comment: try setting either the Max-age of the cookie, or the Expires attribute, not both. I'd keep just the Expires attribute

Answer (score 13):

It might be that your cookie is the HTTPOnly authentication cookie. Those are not shown in chrome unless you're browsing the localhost.

Comment: Any source for that? I can see other HTTPOnly cookies just fine in a non-localhost environment

Comment: That was just my observation. However, it looks like chrome displays a cookie when it has some particular settings. I host my web app locally, on test environment, and production, and I now can only see the prod cookie in dev tools. Unlike local and test, prod cookie has SameSite=strict.

Comment: It was my exact observation too. The server upon authentication return setcookie header with the authentication token. I see that both request and response have the cookie set, and in fact the server also sees the cookie as it does not reauthenticate. However both Chrome and Safari do not display that cookie. When I do local debugging in localhost the cookie is present in the storage.

Answer (score 11):

Below are 2 potential reasons for not actually setting a valid cookie:

1. **Invalid expiration time** - the cookie expires at a time in the past from the browser's perspective
2. **Invalid domain** for the cookie. Let's say you serve the page from *example.com*, but your server tries to set the cookie for domain *google.com*

There could also be a bug in the chrome dev tools to not show your cookies, but you can check that easily by issuing another request to the server and see what cookies are actually received by the server.

Comment: please check the image attached

Comment: an interesting screenshot would be one in which to see the Request/Response headers that are shown by Chrome

Comment: currently i am requesting from localhost:9000 and the node/express server is localhost:8000. so is this reason?

Comment: riyas_tk - Probably

Comment: also https-defined cookies will not be accepted/retained on an http browser session.

Answer (score 4):

If you're certain that the cookie is set and is being sent to the server, but you cannot always see it in the [cookies pane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/storage/cookies) in the developer tools, *check that both the host and the path match the current URL* in the browser. One option which may not always be suitable, is to explicitly set `Path=/` in the cookie, to match all URLs.

##### Details

When you're browsing your site with the developer console open, the cookies pane will show only the cookies that match the current host and path in the URL. For example, if you set your cookie for *subdomain.example.com* but are currently at *example.com*, the cookie for *subdomain.example.com* will not appear, even if it is currently set. Navigate to *subdomain.example.com* and you should now see it in the console.

Likewise, say your Node application at *example.com/api* did not set the `Path` in the cookie and it was automatically set to `Path=/api`. This will only be visible on the console, when and if you browse to a page that starts with *example.com/api/*. Your JavaScript code in the same page, sending requests to *example.com/api* will naturally include this cookie, even though it's not visible on the console, due to the path in the URL being different.

You can see the domain and path for all cookies on the site information pop-up. This is typically done by clicking the icon to the left of the URL, e.g. a padlock if it's HTTPS. Under the cookies section, you can see a box like the picture below for Opera, similar to other browsers.

[image: cookies in use]

Note the path and domain for the selected cookie.

##### Potential Solution

Explicitly set `Path=/` in the cookie. According to the [Set-Cookie MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) for `Path=<path-value>`:

> Indicates the path that must exist in the requested URL for the
> browser to send the Cookie header.
>
> The forward slash (/) character is interpreted as a directory
> separator, and subdirectories are matched as well. For example, for
> Path=/docs,
>
> - the request paths /docs, /docs/, /docs/Web/, and /docs/Web/HTTP will all match.
> - the request paths /, /docsets, /fr/docs will not match.

What is implicit in the above quote, is that using `Path=/` will match all URLs in the given domain. Before taking this approach, you should be certain that it suits all scenarios in your particular use cases.

Comment: Great idea! In my case the UI is loaded from domain1 but the API is hosted on domain2. Same problem, cookies wouldn't show up in the Application tab. When I opened a second browser tab and just picked any of the GET endpoints of the API and navigated to it, the httpOnly cookie showed up. In fact, you probably don't even need to specify a valid GET endpoint of the API. Any URL that for domain2 will probably do to see cookies for that domain, even a URL that results in 404.

Comment: Thank you very much for showing that cookies also might be seen in this additional modal