# Unable to set Cookie using go lang

Tags: angular, go, cookies

I tried looking at videos such [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GWUI5Lf2yZM) and [this link](https://golangcode.com/add-a-http-cookie/). A very similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29179805/cookie-is-not-shown-in-chrome-developer-tools)

I tried my code as below:

```
func articlesHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-headers")
    // var cookie, err = r.Cookie("session_id")
    // // cookie not set
    // if err != nil {
    expiration := time.Now().Add(365 * 24 * time.Hour)
    cookie := &http.Cookie{Name: "session_id", Value: "123123", Expires: expiration}
    http.SetCookie(w, cookie)
    // }
    if r.Method == http.MethodGet {
        articles := Articles{
            Article{Title: "Title 1", Desc: "Desc 1"},
            Article{Title: "Title 2", Desc: "Desc 2"},
        }
        query := r.URL.Query()
        fmt.Println("All Article ENdpoint Hit with ", query.Get("id"))
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(articles)
    }
    if r.Method == http.MethodPost {
        formData := r.FormValue
        fmt.Println("Post call ", formData("id"))
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode("Success")
    }
}
```

I can see in **Response Header**

[image]

But still I cant see it in my Dev Tool ---> Application

[image]

> Because of this, My server is not able to detect the existing `cookie` value. Please help

Comment: Most browsers will not allow setting cookies on `localhost`, nor setting cookies in a response from one site for another site; you issued a request to 127.0.0.1:8080 and the response tries to set a cookie on localhost:4200.

Comment: @Adrian: Does that mean that I can't test any feature related to `cookie` on localhost ? :(  I have backend running on `8080` and frontend app on `4200` .  Is there any workaround ?

Comment: You can't set cookies on `localhost`, but you can on `127.0.0.1`, or on any other IP assigned to your machine, or any hostname you map to your IP in your hostfile. As to the ports - you can generally only set a cookie on the host that's responding with the `Set-Cookie` header, including the port. So if you'll have separate cookies associated with the frontend and backend, and neither will be able to read/write the other's cookies.

Comment: And please use Max-Age instead of Expires. It's 2020 not 1990.

Comment: This is a JavaScript issue, not a problem with Go: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

Comment: @Peter: But then how can someone test on local machine by hosting both client and server?

Comment: I don't understand the question. For cross-origin requests withCredentials must be set, otherwise cookies are ignored. It doesn't matter where the client and server are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Angular` then there is an option to create a proxy and overcome the issue which @Adrian is talking about.

1. Create a `proxy.conf.json` on the same level as `package.json`. Add below entry:

```
{
    "/articles": {
      "target": "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
      "secure": false
    }
}
```

2. Now, make changes in `angular` side to call endpoints as

```
this.httpClient.get('/articles');
```

3. Do **either**

> ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json

**or** update `package.json` with below entry:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
```

and do:

> npm start

and use `http://127.0.0.1:4200/` not `http://localhost:4200`